# get date difference from the columns in dataframe and get seconds -Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two date columns .Now I need to get the difference and the results should be seconds

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(date1, 1, 19)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(date2, 1, 19)) AS delta
```

that hive query I am trying to convert into dataframe query using scala

```
df.select(col("date").substr(1,19)-col("poll_date").substr(1,19))
```

from here I am not able to convert into seconds , Can any body help on this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DataFrame API, you can calculate the date difference in seconds simply by subtracting one column from the other in `unix_timestamp`:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2018-03-05 09:00:00", "2018-03-05 09:01:30"),
  ("2018-03-06 08:30:00", "2018-03-08 15:00:15")
).toDF("date1", "date2")

df.withColumn("tsdiff", unix_timestamp($"date2") - unix_timestamp($"date1")).
  show

// +-------------------+-------------------+------+
// |              date1|              date2|tsdiff|
// +-------------------+-------------------+------+
// |2018-03-05 09:00:00|2018-03-05 09:01:30|    90|
// |2018-03-06 08:30:00|2018-03-08 15:00:15|196215|
// +-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

You could perform the calculation in Spark SQL as well, if necessary:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dfview")

spark.sql("""
  select date1, date2, (unix_timestamp(date2) - unix_timestamp(date1)) as tsdiff
  from dfview
""")
```

Comment: Thanks Leo,that helps